# Java persistent reverse SSH process

Tags: java, process

I am developing an app that creates a process via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])` and opens a reverse ssh tunnel in Linux. I want this tunnel to persist even if the java process is killed.

I read the documentation for `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])` and it specifies that the command is executed in a separate process:

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.

Despite this when the service that runs the java executable is stopped:

```
systemctl stop myapp
```

All active reverse SSH tunnels are closed automatically:

```
Connection to localhost closed.
```

The code that creates the new process is the following:

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    "/usr/bin/sshpass", "-p", request.getHostPassword(),
    "ssh", "-f", "-N", "-M", "-S", "/tmp/socket" + request.getHostUser() + request.getHostIp(),
    "-p", String.valueOf(request.getHostSshPort()), request.getHostUser() + "@" + request.getHostIp()
));
for (SSHPortMapping mapping: request.getPortMappings()) {
    command.add("-R");
    command.add(mapping.getPretty());
}
command.add("-o");
command.add("StrictHostKeyChecking=no");
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toArray(new String[0]));
int result = process.waitFor();
...
```

How may I achieve a persistent process in java that will not close all reverse ssh connections when the service is stopped?

Answer (score 1):

From the commands and their syntax, I will assume an Unix-like system.

The commands started with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` are indeed executed in separate processes but it common that all current childs are killed when a service stops. An easy way it to use an intermediary launcher process.

If it is an option, you could use a tiny shell script that would get the relevant parameters, start the `ssh` commands, and immediately exists without waiting for its childs. From that point, the `ssh` processes having no direct parent are directly *adopted* by the init process (PID 1) and are no longer member of the process group of the java application. Because of that, they should no longer be killed when you stop the service that runs the java executable.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your fast response. I have created a script in `/root/reverse.sh` that will create a subshell inside the process and execute the reverse ssh command: `(sshpass -p password ssh .....)`. Then on the java code I simply call `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("/bin/bash /root/reverse.sh")`. Then I get the process PID with `ps -aux` and I get the PID 1640. Finally I get the PID tree with: `pstree -sg 1640` which outputs: `systemd(1)───ssh(1640)`. So this verifies that the SSH process is owned by `systemd(1)`. Despite all this when I stop the service the process is killed. Any ideas?

Comment: @PauMAVA: I have not programmed like that for years, so I am not sure. I think that recent Linux versions have a process group notion that is not just linked to PPID like what I used in the 80s... If you have no answers here, you could try to ask on Unix&Linux or ServerFault

Comment: Okay, will ask there for the response as it is a PID issue which fits better there I guess. I will upvote your answer as It has led me in the right direction. Thanks!